# Loopback: MySQL functions in order filter

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to use [MySQL functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/func-op-summary-ref.html) in [order filter](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Order-filter.html) with Node API.

The function that I need right now is [FIELD](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php).

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Well Loopback ORM as of this moment doesn't have support for it(and it probably never will) but you can always use the MySQL driver directly:

```
var ids = [4,5,6,7]
YourModel.dataSource.connector.query('SELECT * FROM something ORDER BY FIELD(id, ?)', ids, (err, results) => {
   //...
});
```

But if you want to be database agnostic, you can do it in Javascript:

```
var ids = [4,5,6,7]
SomethingModel.find().then(rows => {
  rows.sort(function (a, b) {
    return ids.indexOf(a) - ids.indexOf(b);
  });
  //...
});
```

Or a little bit faster for larger arrays(by indexing):

```
var idList = [4,5,6,7];
var idMap = {};
idList.forEach(function (id, index) {
  idMap[id] = index;
});
SomethingModel.find().then(rows => {
  rows.sort(function (a, b) {
    return idMap[a] - idMap[b];
  });
  //...
});
```

If you do this in many places across your code, you can also live a little dangerously and monkey-patch [`connector.buildOrderBy`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector/blob/v4.2.0/lib/sql.js#L1168) to do this natively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one question... What happens with the hooks when I use the raw mysql? I'm using pagination (+1M rows) I think the javascript solution is not the appropriate (I thought in Lodash)

Comment: @rigobcastro Since most likely you would be calling `connector.query` in a remote method, by default no hooks are called. You can do that in the remote method as well though to run the hooks: `SomethingModel.notifyObserversOf('before save', context, err => { ... })`